# Получение статуса оплаты из Экваринга

Tags: битрикс

Статус оплаченного заказа, который получает сайт от экваринга проходит на сайт в половине случаев. Чаще всего приходится вручную проверять статус оплаты в экваринге и проставлять его в заказ на сайте. Нужно проверить, чтобы 100% оплат проходили на сайт и передавались успешно в 1С.
Подскажите пожалуйста, типовые шаги в решении этой проблемы.

Comment: Предпологаю нужно запустить логгирование и тестирование заказа

Comment: Посмотрите поддерживает ли ваш эквайринг функцию обратного вызова. Если да, то с помощью неё вы сможете избежать таких проблем

Comment: public function initiatePay(Payment $payment, Request $request = null) нашел такую историю

Comment: Это не то. На стороне эквайринга должна быть возможность вызова АПИ на вашем сервере. Так называемый callback